# How can I turn off visibility of internal users for customer users in Leaderboard and Messages (Experience Cloud Site)

Tags: community, sharing, customer-community, visibility, experience-cloud

I am struggling to configure the site user visibility settings on our experience cloud site. We are building out a help center with a community. We have added the Leaderboard to our homepage. We want the Leaderboard to display customer users only, not internal users. We also would like customer users to be able to send messages to each other, but not to internal users.

I have followed the instructions in [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_user_sharing.htm&type=5), turning on Site User Visibility in Sharing Settings and then enabling "See other members of this community" in the experience administration preferences. After doing those steps I see internal and customer users in the leaderboard and I would like to only see customer users.

We are using a profile for the customer users and a permission set to control article visibility through data categories. I've read through other questions here with similar problems but not exactly like this.

Comment: Are the internal users member of the community?

Comment: No, they are not members of the community. They are just internal employees.

Comment: Thanks for your follow-up question @JefersonChaves. I was able to find a simple solution right in the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. It's embarrassing that I couldn't find this after all the googling and reading I did, but the solution is very simple.

In the Leaderboard component there is a checkbox for the setting "Exclude internal users". If you check that box then internal users will not be visible in the Leaderboard.

I still have to figure out how to disable customer user's from being able to message internal users from the "Messages" page, but the Leaderboard was higher priority since it's so visible.
[image]